# In SVN, how can you tell which branch a revision was checked into?

Tags: svn

Here is the issue we are having:

A developer will have trunk checked out in his sandbox.  We have created a switch script to switch certain files to a branch where changes are being made.  Sometimes the switch script seems to fail, and the developer checks his changes in.  Those changes show up in the revision log, but we can't figure out if they're checked into the branch or trunk.  They seem to get lost on the developer's box.  This causes a lot of switching back and forth and often when it's a small change, it just gets recoded.

So my question is, how can we tell what branch a revision was checked into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using TortoiseSVN, you can get a verbose svn log:

```
svn log --verbose -r HEAD
```

This will show the svn location of all files in the commit (just like @Gilbert Le Blanc's answer). Example output below. Change `HEAD` to the specific revision if you need something different.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r556 | USER | 2012-08-30 13:37:35 -0500 (Thu, 30 Aug 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Path/File.cs

Commit Comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Tortoise, I pulled up a log of a program I modified.

[image: Log messages]

I highlighted the action and path.  The path shows me exactly what was modified, on what branch.

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful, but half my developers are on Macs, so this solution doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 2):

Revisions are per tree, so first you need to get the "changes" for a revision

```
svn diff -r <start revision>:<end revision> --summarize <root svn URL>
```

which might produce output such as

```
A       file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk/src/main/java/com/proj/App.java
A       file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk/src/main/java/com/proj
A       file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk/src/main/java/com
A       file:///home/xx/svn/yyy/trunk/src/main/java
A       file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk/src/main
A       file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk/src
A       file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk/pom.xml
 M      file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk
```

Branches are implemented as directories in SVN, so then you need to determine the root of the project, and which immediate subdirectories are considered (by convention) "branches"

In the example above

```
file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/
```

is considered the "root" url of the project, so subracting that from

```
file:///home/xxx/svn/yyy/trunk
```

tells me that the "branch" it was checked in on was

```
trunk
```

Note that other items were checked in on

```
trunk/src/main/java/com
```

But that is *not* a branch, by *my* convention.  Since the decision of what is a branch is *conventional*, this last determination of which branches were affected is going to require knowledge of your particular SVN setup.  In my case

```
branches/branchA
```

is considered a branch by myself (for my project) but

```
branches/branchA/src
```

is not considered a branch.

Comment: This does give me the information I'm looking for, but I could not get it to work for just one file.

Comment: @DougNoel SVN commits are not single file commits, they are "whole tree" commits.  So if you have a single file, the first step is to determine in which commit it was last modified, which can be determined by `svn info filename`.  If you want the branch for just that file, then filter the diff information for that file.  You never know, but two copies _could_ have been checked in on two different branches with the same commit.